# Force UIApplication openURL to use an existing tab, not open a new one

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, mobile-safari

I'm using the following code to open a url in Safari on the iPad.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

The problem is that I need to open this URL in an existing tab, not open a new one. Is there any way to do this?

*(why?: automated testing framework. I don't want the iPad to be bogged down by having hundreds of tabs open after running for a long period of time)*

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "FORCE" to open URL to open in existing tab. How about you create an iPad application using UIWebView and openURL using custom URL scheme ? Does it help ?

Comment: Unfortunately the UIWebView is not the same as Safari from a functionality point of view. I did consider this but it was found to be too different.

Comment: How about using Skyfire app or any other web browsers for iPad ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to force Safari to load a URL in an existing tab. But I found out that if the exact same URL is already open in an existing tab, that tab is used when calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`. So if you can ensure that you use the same URL in all of your tests, you should be able to avoid "hundreds of tabs".